# Sorting integers in an array. But its not working for some cases

Tags: c++, arrays, integer

So I've written this to print "Yes when the code is in ascending order and "No" when it is not. But if I start with equal values in the beginning, the program prints an incorrect result. I don't understand why the if statement runs even if the condition isn't met.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int N, i;
    scanf("%d", &N);
    int arr[N];

    for(i = 1; i <= N; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d", &arr[i - 1]);
    }

    for(i = 1; i <= N; i++)
    {

        if(arr[i - 1] > arr[i])
        {
            printf("No");
            return 0;
        }
    }

    printf("Yes");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `arr[i]` accesses the array out of bounds on the last iteration when `i == N`.

Comment: your check loop goes until `i <= N` which is out of the bounds.

Comment: fwiw, there is [`std::is_sorted`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/is_sorted). is this an exercise?

Comment: Also note that arrays of non-constant size are not in the standard C++ and don't work on some compilers. Consider using `std::vector` instead.

Comment: `int arr[N];` -- Your program won't sort anything, since this is not allowed in C++.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie come on, it is not standard c++, but a compiler extension, as such it is not the nicest thing, but it does work on compilers that have the extension.

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 I guess the many programmers who have Visual C++ are sad to hear that.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie that's right, when I try to run someone's snippet I often have to replace the VLAs first.

Comment: @Blaze That's just one of the drawbacks from using syntax like that, and that is painstakingly having to convert all of the usage of VLA's to vector if the helping hand uses Visual C++.  Then imagine the post that's riddled with that syntax -- a good portion of whoever could help here just move on to another question.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie In principle I do agree with you, even with a compiler that has the extension I do not see a single good reason to use it

Comment: You need to embrace zero based  counting. Doing it any other way is pure madness. You also need to throw away your C++ learning material and get a good book from the [SO recommended list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list). There are no variable length arrays in C++, and `printf` and `scanf` are not in the `<iostreams>` header (and are not recommended anyway).

Answer (score 1):

You have an off by one error where you skip the first element of your array and go one past the last element. If your array has `N` elements, it goes from `array[0]` to `array[N-1]`. Change this here:

```
for(i = 1; i <= N; i++){
```

To this here:

```
for(i = 0; i < N; i++){
```

The second `for(i = 1; i <= N; i++)` where you do the check can start at `1` since you look at `arr[i - 1]` within, but it should be `i < N` instead of `i <= N` nevertheless.

Furthermore, `int arr[N];` doesn't work in C++ (some compilers will tolerate it, but not all of them). Try `std::vector<int> arr(N);`  instead.

Comment: Also, `scanf()` may fail but there's no error checking for that.